# How I get dynamic name?

Tags: php

Good day.

Me need check 42 names, but it very long:

Useally i use next code:

```
$info_1 = (isset($info['1'])) ? $info['1'] : 0;
$info_2 = (isset($info['2'])) ? $info['2'] : 0;

$info_42 = (isset($info['42'])) ? $info['42'] : 0;
```

Can i get dinamic name?

ex. i want use code:

```
for($i=0;$i<43;$i++){
$info_$i = (isset($info[$i])) ? $info[$i] : 0;
}
```

How aright add `$i` for `$info`?

And is it possible?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using multiple variables instead of an array? Looks like a terrible idea to proceed that way.

Comment: Why don't you use an array?

Comment: i modify question, becose i dont aright copy-paste code, see again please

Comment: @Pierre i modify question, becose i dont aright copy-paste code, see again please

Comment: @EtienneMiret i modify question, becose i dont aright copy-paste code, see again please

Comment: @TeopLome That definitly looks better. But that way, I still don't see the point in setting multiple variables for something you already have in the array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<43;$i++){
    $name = 'info_'.$i;
    $$name = (isset($info[$i])) ? $info[$i] : 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the corresponding manual page: [http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: i modify question, becose i dont aright copy-paste code, see again please

Answer (score 1):

Better use an array:

```
for($i=0;$i<43;$i++){
    $info[$i] = (isset($info[$i])) ? $info[$i] : 0;
}
```

Comment: i modify question, becose i dont aright copy-paste code, see again please

Comment: @TeopLome Your update is a big logical change :) My solution is becoming less important

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
for($i = 0; $i<43; $i++) {
  $var_name = "info_{$i}";
  $$var_name = isset($info[$i])) ? $info[$i] : 0;
}
```

But if you really need this kind of stuff you're doing it real wrong and better off converting this long list of variables to an array;

Comment: i modify question, becose i dont aright copy-paste code, see again please

Answer (score 0):

Just another option:

```
for($i=0;$i<43;$i++){

  ${"info_$i"} = (isset(${"info_$i"}) ? ${"info_$i"} : 0;
}
```

Comment: i modify question, becose i dont aright copy-paste code, see again please